# How can I use score_mode=sum with Elasticsearch multi-match query

Tags: elasticsearch

When I submit my mult-match query below with explain, it appears the scoring is using the highest score of a matched field... I want the sum score of all fields... How can I do that.

```
echo 'Name multi-match BOOSTED query: name.name name.asis name.phonetic name.basename'
curl -sXPOST "localhost:9200/names-test/doc/_search?pretty" -d '{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "William Jurgenson",
            "fields": [ "name.name^1.6", "name.asis^3", "name.phonetic^1.4", "name.basename^1.2" ]
        }
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set `use_dis_max` to `false`. The `multi_match` query defaults to using a `dis_max` query, which will take the max score instead of the sum - setting `use_dis_max` to `false` will use a bool query (which will take the sum).

Source: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/multi-match-query/